# ui.PictureRecorder() gives blank output in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, canvas, flutter, dart

i use ui.PictureRecorder() but it gives a blank output

```
    var pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
    final img = pictureRecorder.endRecording();
    Future<ui.Image> _img = img.toImage(300, 300);
      print('_img:${_img.toString()}');
    canvas.drawImage(_img, Offset(100, 100), Paint());
```

> when i use this then  "The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'." this warning occurs and output is blank

Answer (score 0):

For error message Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image, please change from

```
Future<ui.Image> _img = img.toImage(300, 300);
```

to

```
var _img = await img.toImage(300, 300);
```

and this line will not work

```
canvas.drawImage(_img, Offset(100, 100), Paint());
```

because pictureRecorder adlready endRecording, so there is error

```
Object has been disposed.
```

Comment: so how to handle the issue with object has been disposed?